# Next.js with custom(different) nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have built the frontend part with Next.js so that I can take advantage of SSR and better SEO.
And I do have a custom NodeJS+express server for user management and other DB stuff(Fully working with Postman).

Now I want to integrate next.js with my custom-made NodeJS server, how do I do that there are not many resources available to properly execute this.

Please help me out with this not getting anything, how do I integrate them.

If I directly try to access the NodeJS API via URL, say http://localhost:4000/api/v1/register then next.js will throw CORS error, and how will HTTP cookie work? Or I will have to send the JWT token to frontend and save it into local storage and send it with Bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

`CORS` error might be thrown by node.js. Set the cors in node.js by [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
// this enables All CORS Requests
app.use(cors())
```

In case next.js throws an issue, in next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
          {
            source: '/api/:path*',
            destination: 'https://api.yourNOdeApi/:path*',
          },
        ]
      },
  };
```

In next.js, you write lambda functions in `pages/api` directory. When you make request to outside, you actually send a request to those API routes and inside api routes, you handle the business logic

Comment: Hi @yilmaz thanks for the answer as i have used rewrites to make the call to my backend and it is working fine.
As far as CORS are concerned, should we use CORS in real world application as it will enable all the request to my backend?
There is an issue i found with rewrites is that it does not work with dynamic route, do you have any idea?